# Dozer Field-exclude one-way of private property giving error

Tags: java-7, private-members, dozer

As in the header, I'm trying to map 2 classes, but one of the classes has a private property with a private setter.

```
public Class A {
 private String propertyA;
 private String propertyB;

 ClassA (){
 }
 public String getPropertyA() {
    return propertyA;
 }

 public void setPropertyA(String propertyA) {
    this.propertyA= propertyA;
 }
 public String getPropertyB() {
    return propertyB;
 }

 public void setPropertyB(String propertyB) {
    this.propertyB= propertyB;
 }
} 


public Class B {
 private String propertyA;
 private String propertyB;

 ClassB (String propertyB){
   propertyB = propertyB;
 }
 public String getPropertyA() {
    return propertyA;
 }

 public void setPropertyA(String propertyA) {
    this.propertyA= propertyA;
 }
 public String getPropertyB() {
    return propertyB;
 }

 void setPropertyB(String propertyB) {
    this.propertyB= propertyB;
 }
}
```

I want to map objects from class A to class B and the other way around, with the only difference that propertyB does not need to be set in the mapping from class A to B. 
I've tried it with the following configuration:

```
 <mapping>
  <class-a map-null="false">classA</class-a>
  <class-b>classB</class-b>
  <field>
       <a get-method="getPropertyA" set-method="setPropertyA">propertyA</a>
 <b get-method="getPropertyA" set-method="setPropertyA">propertyA</b>
  </field>
  <field-exclude type="one-way">
       <a get-method="getPropertyB" set-method="setPropertyB">propertyB</a>
       <b get-method="getPropertyB">propertyB</b>
  </field-exclude>
</mapping>
```

This gives me the exception: Property propertyB for class classB cannot be written to.
This was me intention with the private property, but whatever I do, the exception stays. I've tried to add a field mapping with the type="one-way", but this gives me the same exception.
Is there any way to do this with Dozer?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to add `is-accessible="true"` to your definition of `propertyB` for `classB`. This informs Dozer that it should access the attribute directly, rather than through the getter or setter.

You shouldn't have to specify all the getters and setters if they are following the bean standard. Also, if a field is mapping both ways with the bean standard, you shouldn't have to specify it at all. That means you XML **should** be able to look something like this:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a map-null="false">classA</class-a>
  <class-b>classB</class-b>
  <field-exclude type="one-way">
       <a>propertyB</a>
       <b is-accessible="true">propertyB</b>
  </field-exclude>
</mapping>
```